# Is Mactel PPA good stuff for Macbook Pro 5,3 with Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, ppa, macbook, acpi

The Mactel repository proposes some extra packages in order to run Ubuntu on Macbook computers. Mine is a Macbook Pro 5,3 (2009) running Ubuntu 13.04. The wiki page about the Mactel support seems to be quite old: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/PPA

Is it a good idea to add the PPA to my sources or are these packages already integrated to the 13.04 version of Ubuntu? I have some troubles with 13.04 on my MBP, essentially with the power management (I must use ACPI=off in GRUB2 or else I have random freezes).

Comment: It's a very old PPA.  I don't recommend using it.  Fixes to a lot of issues are incorporated into Ubuntu now.